# How to vertically center text relative to a circle

Tags: html, css, geometry, aspect-ratio

Here is what I've tried so far:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-color: #403C36;
  box-shadow: 1px 0.2px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="content">I want this to be centered vertically in the circle</div>
</div>
```

I can't put the text *in* the circle because of the circle's `padding-top` which keeps its aspect ratio at 1:1. However, if there's a way to get around that, I'd be fine with that.

### Update

This cannot be addressed by assuming the width and height of the circle or the content since it is dynamic, based on the window's size, and user-contributed content. It's probably a paragraph or two of text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css: how to draw circle with text in middle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle)

Comment: No this is different because the width and height of the circle is unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this I would suggest

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.circle {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: brown;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: pink;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, tenetur!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far, and I'm probably going to accept it. Just a quick question, would it be possible if the circle and text inside are not centered relative to the page? I'd just have to add another parent element outside `.circle` to determine the location?

Comment: How you center the original circle is up to you...but that's not the topic of this question. The flex properties I applied to the `body` will work on any container of the circle to center **the circle** *in that container*.

Comment: I just tried this and it messed up the formatting of the content. Try adding another `<p>`, it places them side-by-side instead of vertically stacked. Is there any way I can change that?

Comment: Nevermind, I added another wrapper between `.content` and the HTML, it fixed it.

Comment: If you want more than one paragraph add `flex-direction:column` to the content div.

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it, with two divs:

```
<div class="circle">
<div class="text">
TEXT multiline
will be
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {

  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
 padding-top:50%;
  background-color: #403C36;
  box-shadow: 1px 0.2px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position:relative;
}

.text {

  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
width:100%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);

top: 50%;


}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njngv3qk/

Comment: I like this approach as well, but the `flex` directives seem cleaner than using CSS transforms so I'm going with that.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldnt need a wrapper div for this, just one div

HTML

```
<div class="circle">Hello, World</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30%;
  padding: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #001100;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

And, sorry I am unsure of how to create the 'snippets' part of my post.

EDIT updated ratios,

width 1:height 3: width 3

Comment: This doesn't work, that is no longer a circle, it's an oval.

Comment: Keeping `width`, `height` and `padding` identical values will result in a circle

Comment: I've tested some more, and added a new ratio... seems to be much more circular, unless you have width set < 2%

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the text (`content`) inside the (`wrapper`).

This could be a possible solution:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/e9nfca0h/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background-color: #403C36;
  box-shadow: 1px 0.2px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="content">I want this to be centered vertically in the circle</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `top: 45%;` how come you're not using `vertical-align: middle`?

Comment: Nevermind, I see why. This still doesn't truly center the text. At best this assumes a fixed dimension for the `div.content`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts if you change  top: 45%; to top: 50% it will centre the text vertically.

Comment: That's only true if it's one line of text. The size of the content is also unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Change or add following properties into your class content.

HTML

`<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="content">I want this to be centered vertically in the circle</div>
    </div>`

CSS

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 92%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform : rotate(270deg);
}
```