# Create a css responsive circle with centered text content inside an image container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a circle with text inside , centered. This circle must be inside an image full width container. Html should look like this:

```
<div class="class-img">
    <img src="static/img/class-home.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="caption-text"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you tell me how to make this circle and style it to be in the top middle of the container image? I'm using bootstrap 3

This is an snapshot of what I want to create:

[image]

Comment: so you want the circle next to the image...can you add a snapshot of what is the expected

Comment: not sure if this helps you http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/qqOZZN

Comment: I want the circle inside of the image

Comment: check this now http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/qqOZZN

Answer (score 0):

> Use `img-circle` with bootstrap to get image as circle
>
> To create a circle use this css

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;                    //Change  values
    height: 100px;                  //Change  values
    background: red;               //Change color here
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;     //Change  values
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px; //Change  values
    border-radius: 50px;        //Change  values
```

}

Comment: I don't need an image as circle but a circle inside of the image with a caption text inside.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle

Answer (score 0):

```css
.class-img{


}

img{height:500px;width:500px;}
.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 150px;
  
}

.circle{
  background:red;
 
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-top-left-radius:110px ;
    border-top-right-radius:110px ;
    border-bottom-right-radius:110px ;
   border-bottom-left-radius:110px ;
}
.caption-text{
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-img">
    <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png"  class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="caption-text">hello</div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps