# Display rectangular background instead of circular background

Tags: javascript, css

We want to add a Circular background for an `image` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rkEMR/8679/

So I followed [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle) , I am trying below code in the [link2](http://stylebaby.com/yang-yin.html), but its displaying like below `image`, `background` is not circluar:

[image]

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.colors 
{  
width: 30px; 
height: 30px; 
border-radius: 50%; 
background-size: cover !important; 
display: block; 
padding: 0 !important; 
font-size: 0; 
border: 0px solid #d1d1d1 !important;
}
```

**Edit**

**script**

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
var inner = Array(); 
inner = jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label"); 
for (i=0;i<inner.length;i++){ 
var classN = inner[i].innerText; 
if (classN=="Black" || classN=="Green" || classN=="Red" || classN=="Purple" || classN=="Orange" || classN=="Pink" || classN=="Brown"){ 
inner.eq(i).addClass("colors"); 
classN = classN.toLowerCase(); 
var urlB = "http://stylebaby.com/media/catalog/custom/"+classN+".png"; 
inner.eq(i).css('background-image', 'url(' + urlB + ')'); 
} 
} 
});
```

Comment: show HTML or better make sample SO Snippet

Comment: So you're giving the image to the same element of span which is not correct.

Comment: @Justinas we are using javascript for class as `inner = jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label");` i will try fiddle.....

Comment: @YonasHailu sorry for that, please help me what will fix the issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a fixed height and width to the `<span class="label"` here. Preferably give them the same value for the element to be a square.

Apply margin-top to the `label` element for it to be positioned in the center of the `span`

Refer to attached code:

```
.label {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.label label {
    margin-top: 3px !important;
}
```

The result should be like in the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: updated your code, can you please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html) , can you please help me to move the image bit down.....

Comment: The `margin-top` value is getting overriden. Increase specificity and apply `!important`. Update with this: `.label label { margin-top: 3px !important; }`

Comment: also for image, by default `white background displaying` , only orange background should display only after we `mouse-click` on image....

Comment: can you please chcek : http://prnt.sc/dz8sqt you can see `white background is displaying once we open site, but we want to remove that `white-background` , once we click on image  , its displaying `orange` background, thats is fine

Comment: You missed a `;` in your code for `.label` in between `height` & `width`. For the `label` element increase specificity because your code is getting overriden. `.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.colors: margin-top: 3px !important;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133808/discussion-between-user5348fh8y5-and-nashcheez).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set CSS for external rectangle background element like this (Do not forget to add unique class name for this elements like "circular-bg-clr" to avoid conflict with other elements):

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label.circular-bg-clr { 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

After that for inner "color" label you can change your CSS something like this:

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label.circular-bg-clr > label.colors {
    margin: 9px auto !important;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px
}
```