# How to create a circle around text using css?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having trouble finding an example for what i'm specially looking for. I am trying to create a circle around my text using CSS. I've found examples of a circle with the text inside, but in this instance i'm trying to create a circle surrounding the text.

An example of what i'm trying to create:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css: how to draw circle with text in middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `border-radius: 50%` to turn any block element like a `div` with an equal height and width into a circle.

```css
.circle {
  height: 2em; /* just an example size */
  width: 2em;
  border: 4px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

To center the text within the circle, you may want to use flexbox properties on the element as well, though this is not the only way you could achieve that.

```css
.circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: 4px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}
```