# HTML How to draw circle with huge number in exact center?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a single big number like 99 display on a big circle
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615403/css-how-to-draw-circle-with-text-in-middle) and used its code, but the number is not aligned in the exact middle.
here's what I have so far:

```css
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" id="date">99</div>
```

Comment: Easiest way to center both horizontally and vertically: `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`. `line-height` isn't necessary.

Comment: I edited the answer in that question you linked to add an actual explanation of how it works: "Setting a line-height the same value as the height of the div will center the text vertically. In this example the height and line-height are 500px."
The line height trick is very simple and still a good method for such a straightforward task as centering a single bit of text. The line height just needs to match the height of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the line height to be more than the area height.

```
line-height: 300px;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5oevcy0p/)