# Round link with centered text (vertically and horizontally) and active area only the circle, not a square shape

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi, 
Please see the above picture.

I need a link, in the shape of a circle:
- The whole circle should be the active area of the link
- Corners of the square 'behind' the circle should not be active
- Must allow for multiple lines of text in the circle

Note: I can do this fairly easily with table-cell but I need the active area to be only the circle. I dont want the user to be able to hover over the corner of the square behind the circle and click the link.

Thanks

Comment: Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4178z93u/  - you can see when hover over the 'corners' of the circle it is also active.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? The newer browsers dont treat the click-able area as a square.

Comment: testing in modern browser - firefox

Comment: What version of Firefox? You should also test in chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `border-radius` with a fairly big radius. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3gdnkrw/):

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

As to how to center the text in the button: with just one line of text you could simply set the `line-height` of the button to equal its height. But that won't work with multiple lines of text obviously. [Check out this  fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thenewconfection/eYtVN/) from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627283/1519186), it might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

See the following sample. Note the `line-height: 160px;` - this trick aligns the text vertically.

```css
.circle-link{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px darkgreen;
  border-radius: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class='circle-link'>Multiline<br />cyrcle link</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to center text with multiple lines (or even a text with images), the most reliable method is using of flexible model. Instead of `'display: block'` or `'inline-block'` set `display: flex;` or `display: inline-flex;` and then `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`

For more information about vertical centering methods see the article [Vertical centering of elements in HTML](http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/vertical-centering-elements-html)

Comment: I need this to work for multiple lines of text, i think this will only work when there is one line of text only